# Azure DevOps Pipeline: Showing code coverage report for python project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, azure-pipelines-yaml, build-pipeline

I am trying to get code coverage results to show up on the pipeline run summary tab. To debug this, I used a [sample project](https://github.com/Microsoft/python-sample-vscode-flask-tutorial) with the following pipeline.yaml file:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.7'
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.7'

- script: |
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install requirements'


- script: |
    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
    pip install pytest-cov
    pytest --doctest-modules --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml --cov=. --cov-report=xml
  displayName: 'pytest'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/test-*.xml'
    testRunTitle: 'Publish test results'
```

The output of the PublishTestResults task is (**Edit**: As pointed out by the answers, this has nothing to do with the problem since it merely reports the test upload but not the code coverage report upload):

```
Starting: PublishTestResults
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish Test Results
Description  : Publish test results to Azure Pipelines
Version      : 2.180.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results
==============================================================================
/usr/bin/dotnet --version
5.0.301
Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Async Command Start: Publish test results
Publishing test results to test run '324'.
TestResults To Publish 1, Test run id:324
Test results publishing 1, remaining: 0. Test run id: 324
Published Test Run : https://dev.azure.com/.../Runs?runId=324&_a=runCharts
Async Command End: Publish test results
Finishing: PublishTestResults
```

So, it seems that everything works as expected. However, I do not get the results to display on the summary tab (and no code coverage tab appears):
[Screenshot of pipeline summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYYHT.png)

Since I am running out of ideas what to try: Is this feature broken or did I do something wrong?

**Edit**:
It has been suggested to add a PublishCodeCoverageResults-task. However, with the following at the end of the above yaml-file, it still does not work.

```
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.xml'
```

The output of the task is:

```
Starting: PublishCodeCoverageResults
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish code coverage results
Description  : Publish Cobertura or JaCoCo code coverage results from a build
2021-07-21T04:26:34:  -reports:/home/vsts/work/1/s/**/coverage.xml
2021-07-21T04:26:34:  -targetdir:/home/vsts/work/_temp/cchtml
2021-07-21T04:26:34:  -reporttypes:HtmlInline_AzurePipelines
2021-07-21T04:26:35: Writing report file '/home/vsts/work/_temp/cchtml/index.html'
2021-07-21T04:26:35: Report generation took 0.5 seconds
Generated code coverage html report: /home/vsts/work/_temp/cchtml
Reading code coverage summary from '/home/vsts/work/1/s/coverage.xml'
Async Command Start: Publish code coverage
Publishing coverage summary data to TFS server.
 Lines- 17 of 22 covered.
 Branches- 0 of 0 covered.
Modifying Cobertura Index file
Publishing code coverage files to TFS server.
Uploading 8 files
Building file tree
Uploaded 0 out of 1,426,385 bytes.
Uploaded 1,426,385 out of 1,426,385 bytes.
Associating files
Total files: 8 ---- Associated files: 0 (0%)
File upload succeed.
Published '/home/vsts/work/_temp/cchtml' as artifact 'Code Coverage Report_1263'
Async Command End: Publish code coverage
Finishing: PublishCodeCoverageResults
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the Publish Code Coverage Results task.

```
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.xml'
```

**Estension** https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dazfuller.pyunittest-task

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added the PublishCodeCoverageResults-task to the pipeline yaml but still do not get the code coverage results on the summary tab or a dedicated code coverage tab. I edited the question and added the output of the PublishCodeCoverageResults-task.

Answer (score 1):

To see code coverage I think you need to add task PublishCodeCoverageResults@1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops#run-tests

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added the PublishCodeCoverageResults-task to the pipeline yaml but still do not get the code coverage results on the summary tab or a dedicated code coverage tab. I edited the question and added the output of the PublishCodeCoverageResults-task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Coverage.py](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy) to generate the `coverage.xml` report file. After that, it can be published by using the [PublishCodeCoverageResults@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-code-coverage-results-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task. Here is the code snippet of the `azure-pipelines.yaml` file:

```
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.10'
    - script: python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
      displayName: Upgrade pip and setuptools
    - script: python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
      displayName: Install all dependencies
    - script: pre-commit run --all-files
      displayName: Check code quality
    - script: |
        coverage run -m pytest
        coverage xml -o coverage.xml
      displayName: Generate coverage report
    - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
      inputs:
        summaryFileLocation: '**/coverage.xml'
```

First, the **Generate coverage report** task creates the `.coverage` file from which the report is created. The 2nd version of the **PublishCodeCoverageResults** task expects one required parameter, the `summaryFileLocation` field.

Next, you can see the coverage report on the **Code Coverage** tab under the **Pipelines** menu option.

[image: azure_devops_code_coverage]

Answer (score 1):

What is your experience with coverage.py in Azure? Because Cobertura has specific information about code coverage of every file.

PS I was able to get Cobertura working but it took some local testing to see where the files are located when using this package. In the end this worked for me as path:

```
summaryFileLocation: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.xml
reportDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/htmlcov
```